# Python inheritance, super call order and AttributeError

Tags: python, inheritance, attributeerror, python-multiprocessing

I am confused about how inherited class attributes are initialized. I get an `AttributeError` on a child attribute that I thought was well defined.

I noticed that swapping the order of the `super` call to the parent after the definition does not yield an error but I do not understand why.

I have not been able to reproduce that error without using processes (I can post that test code too but I think this is lengthy enough), it seems then that the order in which the super is called does not matter.

**Edit** : It is probably because of running a process before counter is even defined that yiels the exception, but the problem does not happen if I use `Thread` instead of `Process`.

I might be missing something about how initializers work or doing something wrong.

- *Why do I get an Attribute error?*
- *Why swapping the two line solves (or masks) the problem?*
- *Why does this problem does not happen using threads instead of processes?*

I am using the code below.

Thanks for your help.

---

Here is the code that reproduces the issue. I tried my best to make it stand-alone.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._stuff_queue = Queue()
        self._process = Process(target=self._do_something)
        self._process.start()

    def _do_something(self):
        while True:
            stuff = self._stuff_queue.get()
            if stuff is not None:
                self.something(stuff)
            else:
                break

    def feed(self, stuff):
        self._stuff_queue.put(stuff)

    def something(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Implement this something !")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        # --- Swapping those two lines avoids getting the AttributeError --- #
        super(Child, self).__init__()  # Same thing using Parent.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0

    def something(self, stuff):
        self.counter += 1
        print "Got stuff"

c = Child()
c.feed("Hi SO!")
c.feed(None)  # Just to stop
```

Here is the message I get :

```
  File "/home/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test_process.py", line 14, in _do_something
    self.something(stuff)
  File "test_process.py", line 30, in something
    self.counter += 1
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'counter'
```

Comment: `do_something` gets called in `Parent` before you call `self.counter = 0` in `Child`.

Comment: You started a process to call `Child.something` before `self.counter` is ever set.

Comment: Thanks, then why does this not yield an error when starting a thread instead of a process? (I added this detail in the question)

Comment: Because when using a process the instance used in that process will have the state it had at the process creation, and at that time `self.counter` has not been set. Setting it after that won't have an effect, because that's done in a different (the parent) process. If you use a Thread, thenn the call to `c.feed` will always happen after `c` has been fully initialized. If you'd feed it something before setting `self.counter`, then you have a race condition and it may or may not work depending on thread scheduling.